# emssion object is gray in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, emission

Does any one know why when I change the view to cycles render,
The emitting object appear grey here?

[image: The tubes appear grayer even thought it is emitting lights]

[image]

The second image is not in cycles, and it is working fine. The cycles render output is also grayed out

Comment: Have you changed any of your color-management settings?

Comment: no, I haven't touch that!

Comment: Strange, I tested in mine (2.83) just to be sure and emission works same in cycles and eevee. Only way I could get a dimmer effect was to use a filmic-log sequencer and very low contrast. No chance you're using 2.9 or anything like that?

Comment: It’s 2.82 and it works on my other projects. I had a emitter which works in this very file too after deleting that emitting and creating a new object, the whole thing stopped working, no idea why

Comment: This is a long shot, but it's nothing dumb like you have to re-assign the material or something like that? If it's not that, I'm stumped.

Comment: I’ve tried reassigning and it doesn’t work :( I’ll Comment once I figured it out though

Comment: Try to append that object to a new scene to check if that works, also if you could share the file with that object so someone could take a look at it

Comment: so I've copied all the objects into a new file, and it is now displaying everything properly